# Can I use labelled data in unsupervised learning algorithms like neural network?

Tags: python, neural-network, unsupervised-learning

I am working on a transaction dataset that consists of some labeled features like gender, product categories, membership types, and so on. There are also some numeric data like the amount of transactions, number of products, and so on.

I use one hot encoder for all the categorical data and minmaxscaler for all the numeric data.

In this case, can I feed all the categorical data to unsupervised learning algorithms like neural network and KMeans clustering? Do I need to use PCA to convert all the categorical data to numeric data before feeding it to neutral network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course: unsupervised means that it doesn't learn from the labels, but you can use those labels to see if your unsupervised algorithm work well or not.

In your case, I would recommend dimensional reduction algorithms. PCA is a good option, but you will have better results with non linear ones like t-SNE or UMAP.

Answer (score 1):

Neural Network is just one form of machine learning algorithm that can be used for unsupervised learning...

Supervised and Unsupervised learning refers to whether you learn this distribution using a target label for setting the loss function or not.
Meaning, in unsupervised learning using NN you will try to make the network 'learn' the training distribution while in supervised learning you'll learn this same distribution in the context of a specific target.